# How can I use a parametrized MDX query as a data source for a chart in Pentaho Report Desinger?

Tags: reporting, mdx, pentaho, business-intelligence, mondrian

I have the following MDX query in Pentaho Report Designer:

```MDX
SELECT
NON EMPTY TopCount(Order({${Param1}}, [Dim1].[All Dim1], DESC), 6) ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Dim1].[All Dim1]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE CrossJoin({[Dim2].[${Param2}]}, {[Date].[${YearParam}].[${QuarterParam}].[${MonthParam}].[${DayParam}]})
```

Where `Param1` is a list of Measures.

If I add the columns `[Measures].[Measures Levels]` and `[Dim1].[All Dim1]` in the Details as text-field and number-field, I can see the correct results.

But I can't use any of those fields to populate a Chart.

How can I transform this query into one that can be used in charts?

Comment: Why is this the case "But I can't use any of those fields to populate a Chart." ?

Comment: To populate the charts the fields need to be specified. But the measures are declared during runtime, so the field doesn't appear to be used in the chart